# Placing DIV containers inside Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to place containers inside my Bootstrap Carousel slides which will overlay the image with some text and a link. I've got it to be positioned fine and it looks like it works initially, but after going to the next slide it doesn't let you return to the slide with the container. Only the other two. Any idea why this may be happening? Thanks for any help in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihZb6.png)

My code:

```
<div id="wrapper-slides">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div id="box1">
              <br />
              <div id="box1title"><span class="chivoregular">
                  <font color=white>AEROSPACE. MILITARY. COMMERCIAL. SPECIALTY.
                </span></div>
              <br /><br /><br />
              <div id="box1text"><span class="chivolight" style="font-size: 1.25em;">
                  <font color=white>Our customers first choice for quality fasteners.
                </span></div>
              <div id="box1link" class="pointer chivolight hvr-back-pulse">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
              <div id="box1page" class="chivolight">
                1/3
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="images/anasislaunch.jpg" alt="First slide" width="100%">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/f-35.jpg" alt="Second slide" width="100%">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/heli.png" alt="Third slide" width="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="js/carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
```

```
#box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1e366c;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  opacity: 0.95;
    position: absolute;
}

#box1link {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #244080;
  width: 170px;
  height: 18px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#box1page {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#box1text {}

#box1link:hover {
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.carousel {
  position: relative
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease;
  transition: transform .6s ease;
  transition: transform .6s ease, -webkit-transform .6s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px
}

.carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
  display: block
}

.carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}

.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left, .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0)
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d) or (transform-style:preserve-3d)) {
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left, .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
}

.active.carousel-item-right, .carousel-item-next {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%)
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d) or (transform-style:preserve-3d)) {
  .active.carousel-item-right, .carousel-item-next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0)
  }
}

.active.carousel-item-left, .carousel-item-prev {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d) or (transform-style:preserve-3d)) {
  .active.carousel-item-left, .carousel-item-prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
  }
}

.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 15%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .5
}

.carousel-control-next:focus, .carousel-control-next:hover, .carousel-control-prev:focus, .carousel-control-prev:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  left: 0
}

.carousel-control-next {
  right: 0
}

.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  list-style: none
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)
}

.carousel-indicators li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  content: ""
}

.carousel-indicators li::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  content: ""
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #fff
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  border: 0
}

.sr-only-focusable:active, .sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto;
  white-space: normal;
  -webkit-clip-path: none;
  clip-path: none
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your `</font>` tag... or more accurately you should remove it entirely since `<font>` is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="wrapper-slides">
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div id="box1">

     <br />

     <div id="box1title">
      <span class="chivoregular">
       <font color=white>AEROSPACE. MILITARY. COMMERCIAL. SPECIALTY.</font>
      </span> 
     </div>

     <br /><br /><br />

     <div id="box1text">
      <span class="chivolight" style="font-size: 1.25em;">
       <font color=white>Our customers first choice for quality fasteners.</font>
      </span>
     </div>

     <div id="box1link" class="pointer chivolight hvr-back-pulse">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
     <div id="box1page" class="chivolight">1/3</div>
    </div>

    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/&text=1" alt="First slide" width="100%">
   </div>

   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/&text=2" alt="Second slide" width="100%">
   </div>

   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/&text=3" alt="Third slide" width="100%">
   </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Oops.. haha. I wasn't aware the font tag was obsolete either. Thank you!